# Print from JavaScript function to HTML without document.write()

Tags: javascript, document.write

I searched everywhere on here on an alternative on printing to HTML from a JavaScript function to HTML without using document.write() but document.getElementById() doesn't seem to work and I'm really not sure how to go about doing this.

I have this so far

**JavaScript**

```
function trials() {

    while (num_trials > 0) {

        for (var i = 0; i < random.length; i++) {
            document.write(random[i]);
        } 
    }
}
```

Where "random" is an array of letters

**HTML**

```
    <div id ="container">
    <center>
        <i>**TRIALS HERE**</i><br><br>
        <font size="8">
        <script>trials();</script><br><br>
        </font> 
    </center>
</div>
```

I'm also looking for a way to hide each letter after each iteration of the for-loop so that it doesn't just print as a long string of letters.

Comment: It's `document.getElementById()`, not `getElementFromId()`.

Comment: Well, using a for loop would also be wrong if you want to hide them and have the people see each iteration.

Comment: @epascarello do you have any suggestions for how I could print consecutive letters from an array without a for-loop?

Comment: setTimeout or  setInterval

Comment: All of these answers will work, but you will kick yourself later for not just using templating like http://handlebarsjs.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic idea is to use an interval to loop through the array so there is a delay. You want to set the text with innerHTML or textContent.

```js
(function() {

    var outputElem = document.getElementById("outputSpot"),  //where to output the letter on the screen
        current = 0,  //start index in the array
        randomChars = ["W","E","L","C","O","M","E","!"],  //characters to show
        timer = window.setInterval(  //this is how we will loop with an interval
            function () {
                var letter = randomChars[current];  //get next letter
                if (letter) {  //if there is no letter, it will be undefined and we will be done
                    outputElem.innerHTML = letter;  //show the letter to the user
                    current++;  //update the index
                } else {
                    window.clearInterval(timer);  //cancel the timer since we ran out of things to display
                }
            }
        ,1000);  //number of seconds to wait between iterations

}());
```

```html
<span id="outputSpot">Hello!</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**

I would try setting the div to a variable:

```
var div = $('#container');
function trials() {
    while (num_trials > 0) {

        for (var i = 0; i < random.length; i++) {
            div.appendTo(random[i]);
    } 
}
```

**HTML**

Then maybe hiding the container div (style='display:none;') would prevent the numbers printing out, but still accessible:

```
<div>
    <center>
        <i>**TRIALS HERE**</i><br><br>
        <font size="8">
        <script>trials();</script>
        <div id="container" style="display:none;"></div><br><br>
        </font> 
    </center>
</div>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution requires using jQuery. Also I wouldn't make the style "display:none;" because they want the user to see each letter.

Comment: Definitely good to mention the jquery usage there at the top.  I see now I misread how he asked to hide the letter after each loop.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You can edit your answer if you want, but another problem is that it should probably use setTimeout or setInterval to make sure each letter is displayed for long enough to see.

Answer (score -1):

It may be very useful for you to use JQuery.

```js
function trials() {

    while (num_trials > 0) {

        for (var i = 0; i < random.length; i++) {
            $('#iToWrite').html( $('#iToWrite').html() + random[i]);
        } 
    }
}
```

```html
<div id ="container">
    <center>
        <i id='iToWrite'>**TRIALS HERE**</i><br><br>
        <font size="8">
        <script>trials();</script><br><br>
        </font> 
    </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is there document.write in the answer?